# FFmpeg loop video for 30 seconds generate a big video size

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to loop a 3 sec video to make it 30 sec, I use the following command :

```
> ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -c copy -t 30 output.mp4
```

It's working fine, but with the output size **40 MB**, it's abnormally to have a 30 sec video with **40 MB** as size.

Kindly, how I can generate a 30 sec video file from 3sec video, but with smaller size

Comment: What's the size of the input?

Comment: @Gyan the size is 1mb